# ADT Get new Platform versions

Tags: cordova, adt, android-version

I'm using ADT v22.0.1-685705 on a MAC.

I can try my app on virtual devices using Platform 2.2 to 4.x (API level 8 to 17).

I'd like to be able to test on a 2.1 virtual device which is the lowest for a phonegap 2.6.0 app.

How can I get a 2.1 virtual device ?

[image: ADT]

Answer (score 0):

Found :

/Users/alain/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools

> android